# Robot Framework : How to use test time out for test case

Tags: robotframework

I have test suit which has multiple test cases and to avoid execution halt of test suite , I wants to add test time out for each test case . How to do this please help.

Comment: I tried test time out keyword but faced below error -                                           No keyword with name 'Test Timeout' found.

Answer (score 6):

According to the [robot framework user guide](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#timeouts), you define the default timeout in the settings. This is the example from the user guide:

```
*** Settings ***
Test Timeout    2 minutes
```

You can specify a test case or keyword specific timeout with the `[Timeout]` setting:

```
*** Test Cases ***
Example
    [Timeout]    1 minute
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you could use the built in Wait conditions

```
Wait For Element To Be Visible   ${ELEMENT_LOCATOR}   30s
```

These have a second argument for timeout.